# How to create a cube formed by 600 000 000 mini-cubes per side with ThreeJs?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I would like to recreate a cube like in the game *curiosity what's inside the cube?* formed by 600 000 000 mini-cubes per side. I can't use a texture to simulate my mini-cubes because there must be a visual change on a mini-cube when I click on it.

I tried a `BoxGeometry()` object with 2 faces as a mini-cube

```
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        alpha: true
    });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    //There is my cube
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 20, 20, 24494, 24494, 24494);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xfd59d7
    });

    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);

    camera.position.z = 100;

    render();

    function render() {
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
```

So how could I create a cube with 600 000 000 mini-cubes per side that could be rendered on a notebook?

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also keep in mind that you're asking quite a bit from a single mesh. `BoxGeometry(50,50,50, 500, 500, 500)` will produce a mesh with 500,000 triangles PER SIDE. THREE.js can handle millions of triangles in its scene, but having 3 million of those in a single mesh/draw call is a bit much. Consider splitting your "cublets" into individual meshes.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to improve my answer. Will threejs perform better whith 600 000 000 square meshes per side than one cube mesh with 1 200 000 000 triangles per side?

Comment: I can't recall now, but I thought your original post had fewer squares per side. Look at it this way: If you draw just the outer face of each mini-cube, at 600 000 000 per side, that's 1 200 000 000 triangles. Speaking from personal experience, I've seen framerates plummet after just 30 000 000 triangles (nothing fancy, just a single render pass), and that's on a desktop.

Comment: Yes, in my original post I gave a more reasonable number but my goal is to copy the game _curiosity_ so I tried to clarify my post. Developers of curiosity used **unity** but the game ran on smartphone!! How is it possible??

Comment: Perhaps someone with more experience with Unity can chime in here, but you're looking at the difference between running in a web browser versus running on native hardware. The native application (even if it's within the Unity framework) will naturally run better. The developer may have also used rendering techniques not available with WebGL (geometry and compute shaders, for example).

Comment: Ok, I understand, thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can guarantee you that Curiosity does not actually display a cube made from 600,000,000 cubes per side. No current GPU can draw 600,000,000 cubes at a smooth framerate. As pointed out above that's 7.2 billion triangles per side. You can see 3 faces of a cube at once so at 30fps that would be 648 billion triangles per second. Even an NVidia 1080 GT (a near top performance card in 2017) can only draw a theoretical 11 billion triangles per second and that's only theoretical. In reality it will never reach that speed.

At best in Curiosity, when you can see the entire cube it just displays a single 12 polygon cube with textures where a pixel represents more than 1 cube (if there really are 600,000,000 cubes per side) as that would require a texture of 24494x24494. [That's 5x to 10x what any phone can display in a single texture](http://webglstats.com/webgl/parameter/MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE?platforms=000000340010800400). Yes you could subdivide the face of a cube into smaller polygons each using a different texture. That would require 2.3gig of textures PER side or 13.4gig of memory for the entire cube. Phones don't have 13.4 gig of memory.

If it really is 600 million cubes per side the best you could do is something like google maps where all the data is stored on the server and various representations are streamed to the user. When the user is zoomed out to see the entire cube some representation of say 1024x1024 per side (1 million pixels) is shown and as you zoom in different representations showing a smaller portion of the cube are downloaded and shown.